# Не вижу app, после debug

Tags: android, android-studio

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: после дебага, не появляется иконка приложения, на эмуляторе и на живом устройстве. Если зайти в настройки, то там она висит, можно только удалить, но запустить заново не могу. Кто знает, как решить это в Android Studio?

Comment: Может у вас в манифесте исчез Интент фильтр у активити

Comment: там все ок, не в этом дело. Манифест не менялся.

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов несколько может быть, но есть последовательность, которая исправит это дело в большинстве случае.

Заходим в настройки и удаляем app ручками, или через adb.

Заходим в build.gradle (нужный проект):

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Зависит от того используете вы native часть или нет, иначе будет проще.
После `Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB intergration`

После RebuildProject, далее в зависимости от пожелания можно включить интеграцию, но советую вначале запустить проверить, а потом менять. 
Должно помочь.

Comment: Я весь день на это потратил, сделал как вы написали только что и всё сразу заработало! Вы просто БОГ, всё работает!!! Вы меня спасли и сэкономили уйму времени, спасибо огромное. ☺☺☺

Comment: Добро пожаловать) !